# VB.Net Pass Type as Reference

Tags: vb.net

I have this function:

```
Private Sub GetControl(ByVal ctrl As Control, ByVal ctrlType As Type)
...
End Sub
```

I want to be able to get either a ComboBox, TextBox, or Label by passing in the Type. However, If I call GetControl(ctrl, ComboBox), it says ComboBox is a type and can't be used as an expression. Is there any way around this other than creating an object of type ComboBox, and passing in the object.GetType? I don't want to be creating an object whose sole purpose is to pass in a Type. Thank you.

Comment: what are you getting the controls from?  from the looks that should be a function returning a control

Comment: I like to simplify my code as much as possible to make a clearer example.. you are right it is returning a control. I should have left that in my bad

Comment: I smell an XY problem. `GetControl(ctrl, GetType(ComboBox))`

Comment: `what are you getting the controls from`?? if it is the form's control collection there is already a means in place

Comment: GetType(ComboBox) worked, thank you

Comment: Yes, I am getting the controls from the form's control collection

Comment: there is already a `Me.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)` way to do it

Comment: Doesn't that pass an IEnumerable or a List.. I can't remember..., not a type?

Comment: The second argument is redundant. You can pass just one argument (`ctrl As Control`) and get the type inside the function via `ctrl.GetType()`.

Comment: I'm not sure how GetControl will ever get a specific control without a name.  try `Me.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)().Where(Function(w) w.Name = findName).FirstOrDefault`  note that the return can be nothing if there is no matching name

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå if your correction is exactly what the OP is looking for (= always passing the type of `ComboBox` as an argument), it wouldn't make too much sense (passing always the same argument?! Why not declaring a local variable rather than unnecessarily typing more every time you are calling this sub?). `GetType(ctrl)` would make more sense, but even though is not required (as far as this information can be extracted from `ctrl`).

Comment: I have a DatabaseLabel, DatabaseComboBox, ServerLabel, and ServerComboBox Type. Since I have multiple servers and databases, each DatabaseLabel and DatabaseComboBox has a ServerID and DatabaseID while the ServerLabel and ServerComboBox only have a ServerID. I am identifying the controls by the ServerID and the DatabaseID because they are dynamically created in the designer. No reason to explain all of this when I can ask a simple question that Bjorn answered, I have my reasons!

Comment: `I am identifying the controls by the ServerID and the DatabaseID` you *could* have a [class widget](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33785399/1070452) of some sort track them for you rather than fish around for them

Comment: That's interesting, and I am using the same eventhandlers for each database combobox so that could be added into the class as well.

Comment: Not for nothing, but that is why we ask odd-sounding questions sometimes: it often sounds to (some of) us like there is an easier way to do something.  All the way thru typing that answer I had feelings of deja vu that it could apply to some other Q recently asked.  Later I remembered which one.